# Need advice for Android multiple resolution design

Tags: android

For example, I'd like to show an image in screen. Here are the size and dpi:

```
LDPI - 0.75x                  75x75             120 dpi
MDPI - Original size          100x100           160 dpi
HDPI - 1.5x                   150x150           240 dpi
XHDPI - 2.0x                  200x200           320 dpi
XXHDPI - 3x                   300x300           480 dpi              
XXXHDPI - 4.0x                400x400           640 dpi
```

But the display for two devices is not what I want.

[image]

[image]

The first device is 480x800, 240 dpi. The second device is 800x1280, 213 dpi.The bigger screen has lower dpi. I need some advices on how to handle this case? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see is that your first device is a mobile while the second is a tablet. So you can provide alternate layout files for mobile's and tablets. See [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information. For this case for mobile you can use **layout-sw720dp** folder and for the bigger tablet screen. As for the images your current settings above will work great.